# Flutter Firestore FieldValue.delete() crashes my app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a certain field from firestore when my user swipes 'delete' on my app. However, whenever I do this I either get the Errors:

```
Future<void> deleteItem(
  String location,
  String sellerName,
  String uid,
  String itemName,
) async {
   if (laCityList.contains(location)) {
      var data = {};
      data[uid] = {itemName: FieldValue.delete()};
      print('THis is in data: ${data}');
      await dbReference.collection('Items LA').document(location).updateData(data);
  }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

or If I do:

```
Future<void> deleteItem(
  String location,
  String sellerName,
  String uid,
  String itemName,
) async {
  if (laCityList.contains(location)) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data[uid] = {itemName: FieldValue.delete()};
    print('THis is in data: ${data}');
    await dbReference
        .collection('Items LA')
        .document(location)
        .updateData(data);
  }
}
```

Error:

> Lost Connection to Device

My firestore is structured as:

```
Items -> City -> {UserId: {ItemName : {ItemInformation}}
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong and would love to have your help

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing same error...........

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: type '\_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614128/unhandled-exception-type-internallinkedhashmapdynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-su)